# The switch turns function not working in Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, html

(Please use basic methods if possible to solve this issue. I am still an absolute beginner so I don't want to confuse myself) I am trying to create a function called changeturns so that when I run this function in the startGame function the turn can automatically change between X and O.  However the turns only change after one round of playing by a single player(i.e. it only switch to X after O has won).

```js
var arrayx = [];
var turn = "O";
var scoreX = 0;
var scoreO = 0;

  
function refresh() {
  for (var cell = 0; cell < 9; cell++) {
    document.getElementById("cell" + cell).innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function changeturns(turn) {

 
}

function startGame(cell) {
 
  
  document.getElementById("cell" + cell).innerHTML = turn;
  checkwin(turn);
}

function checkwin(turn) {
 }
   

startGame(); // should not be called here
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fdd;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-155px;
    top:50px;
    background-color:pink;
}

td{
  border:2px solid#333;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS",cursive;
  font size: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table tr:first-child td{
  border-top:0;
}

table tr:last-child td{
  border-bottom:0;
}

table tr td:first-child{
  border-left:0;
}

table tr td:last-child{
  border-right:0;
}

.endgame{
  display:none;
  width:200px;
  top:120px;
  color:white;
  font size:2em;
  background-color:rgba(304,144,66,0.7)
}
```

```html
<h1>Wanna Play Tic Tac Toe?</h1>
<p id="qiguai">
    <b>O player scoreboard</b>
</p>
    
<p id="roundannouncer"> 
</p>
<p id="qiguai2">
    <b>X player scoreboard</b> 
</p>
<p id="roundannouncer2">    
</p>
<table id="myTable" width="400" height="400">
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="cell0" onclick="startGame(0)"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="cell1" onclick="startGame(1)"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="cell2" onclick="startGame(2)"></td>
  </tr>
      
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="cell3"  onclick="startGame(3)"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="cell4" onclick="startGame(4)"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="cell5" onclick="startGame(5)"></td>
  </tr>
      
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="cell6"  onclick="startGame(6)"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="cell7"  onclick="startGame(7)"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="cell8"  onclick="startGame(8)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="endgame">
  <div class="text">
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="refresh()"> Replay </button>
```

I tried to call the function inside and outside the startGame function but neither works.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS so we can reproduce your issue and show you how you can solve your problem with about 25 less lines of code.

Comment: OK. Here is the link https://glitch.com/edit/#!/inexpensive-serpent?path=index.html:6:57

Comment: @ScottMarcus . Actually I am not looking the most efficient way to solve this. I just want a little modification that switch the turns without changing too much of my original structure.

Comment: I added a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to your question. All you need to do is copy the HTML from where it is to the snippet's HTML box.

Comment: I completed this snippet with the HTML & CSS as present in the link you gave. You can now see that the code produces an error, which is a great hint towards the problem you have. You should always check the console for errors.

Comment: @trincot  Thank you Hi I marked your answer as accepted. Could you delete the snippet? My previous version is too specific.

Comment: What do you mean "too specific"? As your question was before it did not have enough information (the HTML and CSS was missing), and now you removed code that is needed to actually reproduce the problem. Also don't add a comment in the *question* indicating the solution. Answers should be in the answer section, not in the question. And questions should have all the code to be able to reproduce the problem. I think you should roll back your last update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `checkwin` function calls `startGame` again, and so the turn is also toggled again. Then an error occurs because `startGame` was called without an argument.

You should never call `startGame` where you have it now in the code. Remove those two instances. The only place to call `startGame` is from the click event handlers (which you have defined in HTML `click` attributes).

Note that the name `startGame` is confusing, because it actually does not *start* the game, it plays a move. This is probably also the reason why you had introduced this error. Using a good name for a function (and variable) is important.

Comment: Great it's now fixed I think